# ¿porque no me deja usar pthread_abort y que alternativas exiten?

Tags: c, hilos

Tengo un servidor en c para linux que cada vez que recibe a un cliente crea un hilo con un while que se encarga de comprobar si el cliente está conectado. En el caso de que se desconecte este hilo lo saca de la lista de clientes conectados.

El problema es que hay casos en los que saco voluntariamente a los clientes de la lista y necesito que el hilo que se encarga de verificar si hay conexión deje de funcionar instantaneamente. Para eso pensaba usar `pthread_abort();` pero aunque he encontrado información sobre la función en internet no me deja usarla en el programa.

Esta es la función que ejecuta el hilo que quiero abortar:

```
    char ejemplo;
    bool pasa = false;

    while(!pasa)
    {
        if(1>recv(fd,&ejemplo,1,MSG_PEEK))
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("deconexion del cliente %d.",fd);
            pasa = true;
        }
    }

    // aqui elimina al receptor de la lista cuando se desconecta el cliente
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    eliminarReceptor(indice);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

(no quiero que la funcion siga consumiendo recursos con el recv y poner un if en la parte de desconectar al cliente)

¿existe alguna forma de usar pthread_abort() u alguna alternativa?

Comment: La verdad, no conozco `pthread_abort( )`. POSIX (y Linux) tienen [`pthread_cancel( )`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). ¿ Cabría la posibilidad de que estés confundido con el nombre de la función ?

Comment: muchas gracias eso era